# "~a country the size of Arizona." What is omitted/missing between 'a country' and the 'size~'?

Tags: sentence-construction

"300 million people will live in a country the size of Arizona." 
+ What is omitted/missing between 'a country' and the 'size~'?

Comment: Nothing is 'omitted'. What did you expect to see there?

Comment: 'A country' is a noun and 'the size of Arizona' is a noun as well..? So I thought there's something between them grammatically.

Comment: "the size of" is a phrase meaning "the same size as".

Comment: I meant I don't understand why 'a noun+another noun' form is happening here but I searched some more and I think if the two things indicate the same thing, like "My daughter Ellen", it is grammatically correct. Thank you for the reply~!

Comment: "that is" is what's missing--"a country that is the size of Arizona"